# Porting breadth-first search to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm

I created AI for snake in Python. The game works nicely. I started learning Javascript recently and I tried writting the Javascript equivalent of the game.

The game is played on x*y grid (eg. 30*20). In Python I used (x, y) tuples for game position. In JS I use integers which I map ussing:

```
function map(x, y) {
    return x + y * size.width;
}
function unmap(pos) {
    return {x: pos % size.width, y: Math.floor(pos/size.width)};
}
```

My problem is that the search doesn't work. When I try to create path from it enters infinite loop. The search function is:

```
function search(start, goal) {
    var frontier = new PriorityQueue({
        comparator: function(a, b) {
            return a.score - b.score;
        }
    });
    frontier.queue({value: start, score: 0});
    var cameFrom = {};
    cameFrom[start] = null;

    while (frontier.length !== 0) {
        var current = frontier.dequeue().value;
        if (current === goal) {
            break;
        }

        var nbs = neighbors(current);
        for(var i = 0; i < nbs.length; i++) {
            var next = nbs[i];
            if (Object.keys(cameFrom).indexOf(next) === -1) {
                var priority = heuristic(goal, next);
                frontier.queue({value: next, score: priority});
                cameFrom[next] = current;
            }
        }
    }
    return cameFrom;
}
```

I use [this priority queue](https://github.com/adamhooper/js-priority-queue).

The search in Python is more OOP but I don't want to include more code - the question is already long. But I'll include the search:

```
def search(self, grid, start, goal):
    frontier = PriorityQueue()
    frontier.put(start, 0)
    came_from = {}
    came_from[start] = None

    while not frontier.empty():
        current = frontier.get()

        if current == goal:
            break

        for next in grid.neighbors(current):
            if next not in came_from:
                priority = self.heuristic(goal, next)
                frontier.put(next, priority)
                came_from[next] = current

    return came_from
```

If anything more is needed please ask. I'm bad at JS.

Comment: Forgot most of the little JS I knew, but why do `Object.keys(cameFrom).indexOf(next) === -1` instead of just `cameFrom[next] == -1`?

Comment: @IVlad That line is true if the key's not there (I'm not testing for value, but for existence). But it could be simplified to `cameFrom[next] === undefined`.

Comment: @IVlad I refactored the line (to `cameFrom[next] === undefined`) and it works now! I thereby proclaim you genius. (I think that my line wasn't working at all - or was doing something different) Post it as asnwer. (I have no problem answering it myself, but I wanted to give you the chance)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it :). It was mostly a lucky guess really, so please feel free to self answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with this line:

```
if (Object.keys(cameFrom).indexOf(next) === -1) {
```

I was searching for integer but keys are always strings. You can clearly the behavior in this example:

```
var foo = {0: "fooBar", 1: "bar"};
console.log("keys", Object.keys(foo));
console.log("int", Object.keys(foo).indexOf(0)); // -1
console.log("string", Object.keys(foo).indexOf("0")); // 0
```

This is more readable, shorter and works:

```
if (cameFrom[next] === undefined) {
```

Thanks to [IVlad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508409/porting-breadth-first-search-to-javascript?noredirect=1#comment52878025_32508409) who pointed out the bad line.